# MySQL: Advanced insert if not exists

Tags: mysql, key, duplicates

I have a table with with essentially three columns: user_id, setting, and value. I'm trying to use the following code:

```
INSERT INTO 'user_settings'(user_id, setting, value)
VALUES (1234, setting_1, 500)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = 1234, setting = setting_1'
```

This works great when creating a new setting, and it doen't generate duplicate records. The problem comes when I want to change the value- this won't work after the previous query has run:

```
INSERT INTO 'user_settings'(user_id, setting, value)
VALUES (1234, setting_1, 999)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = 1234, setting = setting_1'
```

No rows are affected.  Clearly I'm missing something...

**IMPORTANT**: I am not able to alter the database (new primary keys or something).

**UPDATE**: It seems my understanding of `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is wrong. But the question remains- what is the most efficient way way to accomplish this?

**Answered in a comment below**: "If the Primary (or Unique) key is (user_id, setting), then use: ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=999".

Comment: and what is the primary key ?

Comment: I'd say you shouldn't assign `user_id` in the UPDATE part, because that's already the key which caused he insertion error.

Comment: The primary key isn't listed- there's more columns in the table that aren't really relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually have a unique key on `user_id`, you are getting "no rows affected" because you aren't changing anything in the second query.  I think what you want to do is update the `value` field as well:

```
INSERT INTO 'user_settings'(user_id, setting, value)
VALUES (1234, setting_1, 999)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE setting = setting_1,value=999
```

Without `value` in there, you're just setting the `user_id` and the `setting` field to the same values they were before, and MySQL doesn't need to update the record.

If you don't have a unique key on `user_id`, you'll have to find a different approach, as the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` won't trigger.

Comment: There isn't a unique key on `user_id`, so it seems I am using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` wrong. Any ideas what approach I should be using?

Comment: @Luke: What is the PK? And are there any other Unique keys on the table?

Comment: If the Primary (or Unique) key is `(user_id, setting)`, then use: `... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=999`.

Comment: There's another couple of columns that aren't really relevant- an `id` and a `timestamp` column.  `user_id` and `setting` aren't unique. A single user will have multiple settings, and multiple users will have the same setting. But a single user can't have duplicate settings with different values.

Comment: @ypercube, you did it! It turns out our brilliant DBA had already set up `(user_id, setting)` as unique. I wish you had posted that as an answer instead of a comment, as I would mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @Luke: No problem. You can mark zombat's answer as correct. He meant the same thing, just didn't guess the correct Unique key :)